# css - border-right of a td element overflow border-bottom

Tags: css

I have a table and I applied the border on `td` elements inside of it, now when I hover a `td` I want the `tr` to be selected by changing the borders of `td` elements inside, but the right border of a `td` is on top of the bottom border, so the corner doesn't change color, and I do not want this to happen. Any ideas?

**CSS**

```
.advertisements table {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.advertisements table td {
    border: 2px solid #F3FAFF;
    padding: 10px;
}
.advertisements table tr {
    background-color: #9EC630;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#9EC630, #87AB29);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#9EC630, #87AB29);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#9EC630, #87AB29);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #9EC630), color-stop(1, #87AB29));
    filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr=#9EC630, EndColorStr=#87AB29)";
    background: linear-gradient(#9EC630, #87AB29);
}
.advertisements table tr:not(:first-child):hover {
    background-color: #B8D669;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#B8D669, #9EC630);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#B8D669, #9EC630);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#B8D669, #9EC630);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #B8D669), color-stop(1, #9EC630));
    filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr=#B8D669, EndColorStr=#9EC630)";
    background: linear-gradient(#B8D669, #9EC630);
}
.advertisements table tr:not(:first-child):hover td {
    border-top: 2px solid #1A446C;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #1A446C;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.advertisements table tr:not(:first-child):hover td:first-child {
    border-left: 2px solid #1A446C;
} 
.advertisements table tr:not(:first-child):hover td:last-child {
    border-right: 2px solid #1A446C;
}
.advertisements table tr td ~ table tr:not(:first-child):hover {
    border-top: none;
} 
.advertisements table tr:first-child:hover {
    cursor: default;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="advertisements">
  <table>
  <tr>
   <td>1</td>
   <td>2</td>
   <td>3</td>
   <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>1</td>
   <td>2</td>
   <td>3</td>
   <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>1</td>
   <td>2</td>
   <td>3</td>
   <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Source is here: http://dabblet.com/gist/c0a22609e6139ad83546

Comment: can you post image with what kind of output you are looking?

Comment: Would be better to include important code directly in the question, since links don't always last forever. (see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question lies in the way browsers [resolve border conflicts](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#border-conflict-resolution).

You can set the `tr` border to be a bit wider, or change the `border-style`, etc...

If you're unhappy with any of these, I suggest looking at a more complex solution, like [border gradients](http://css-tricks.com/examples/GradientBorder/).

Answer (score 1):

Check if this could help you.

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mrvlx)

HTML

```
<div class="advertisements">
  <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" >
  <tr>
   <td><div>1</div></td>
   <td><div>2</div></td>
   <td><div>3</div></td>
   <td><div>4</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><div>1</div></td>
   <td><div>2</div></td>
   <td><div>3</div></td>
   <td><div>4</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><div>1</div></td>
   <td><div>2</div></td>
   <td><div>3</div></td>
   <td><div>4</div></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.advertisements table {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    /* border-collapse: collapse; */
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.advertisements div {
  background-color: #9EC630;

    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#9EC630, #87AB29);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#9EC630, #87AB29);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#9EC630, #87AB29);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #9EC630), color-stop(1, #87AB29));
    filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr=#9EC630, EndColorStr=#87AB29)";
    background: linear-gradient(#9EC630, #87AB29);
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
  border-top: 2px solid #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
}
.advertisements div:after {
  width: 4px;
  background: #fff;
  content: " ";
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.advertisements tr:hover div {
  border-color: #1A446C
}
.advertisements tr:hover td:first-child div:before {
  width: 2px;
  background: #1A446C;
  content: " ";
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.advertisements td:last-child div:after {
  display: none
}
.advertisements tr:hover td:last-child div:after {
  width: 2px;
  background: #1A446C;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I would use it if no better solutions will occur.

Answer (score 0):

I find this question quite interesting so I tried to do some edits to it.

I didn't find the solution you are looking for yet, but I found out something interesting for me at least:

- If you set the borders of `td` to be `1px` wide at start and the hover ones to be `2px` wide it works quite fine I would say: http://jsfiddle.net/Ax9eL/6/

But yeah this solution makes the table move which is not good/nice.

- One more thing I tried `border-collapse: separate; border-spacing:0px;` instead of `border-collapse: collapse;` which doesn't look very good either: http://jsfiddle.net/Ax9eL/15/

Hope that someone might come up with better solutions ;)

Comment: BTW I have noticed myself that if I apply bigger border width it works, but I wouldn't like the table to move in place. In the second exapmle there is a separation can be noticed, so I would better try the first example than risking the cross browser compatibility and getting nothing insted of it. BTW thanks a lot for trying to help :)